# Is it correct to use a colon in this case, as opposed to a semi-colon?

Tags: punctuation

(sorry, straight from my History notes)

*Woodrow Wilson was pleased that he had successfully persuaded his partners to accept that the Covenant of the League of Nations should be included in all the peace treaties **:** this would help to realise his vision of a global peacekeeping organisation.*

or should it be,

*all the peace treaties; this would help to realise*

I previously thought colons could be used to give an explanatory or additional cause (ie explains why he was pleased). Am I right?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Please define "correct" for us.

Comment: British English?